# Cart page doesn't show anything in E-Commerce project developing by Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart

In my E-Commerce project, cart page is not working. Cart page is shown as an empty page. I installed ***composer require "darryldecode/cart"*** this cart package to my project. This is the first project, I couldn't find out the error. It would be a great help if give hand to sort out this problem.

**CartController.php**

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
    
class CartController extends Controller
{

    public function add(Product $products)
    {
        dd($products);
    
        // add the product to cart
        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->add(array(
         'id' => $products->id,
         'name' => $products->prod_name,
         'price' => $products->prod_price,
         'image' => $products->prod_image_path,
         'quantity' => 1,
         'attributes' => array(),
         'associatedModel' => $products
       ));
       return redirect()->route('products');     
   }
    
   public function index()
   {
        $cartItems = \Cart::Session(auth()->id())->getContent();
        return view('cart')->with(compact('cartItems')); 
    }
}
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cartItems as $item)
   <tr class="">
     <td class="text-center">
          <a href="#" class="text-gray-32 font-size-26">×</a>
     </td>
                                      
     <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">
         <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid max-width-100 p-1 border border-color-1" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$item ['image'] ) }}" alt="Image Description"></a>
     </td>
                                        
     <td data-title="Product">
         <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $item ['name'] }}</a>
     </td>                                  
     <td data-title="Price">
         <span class="">LKR {{ $item ['price'] }}.00</span>
     </td>
                                       
     <td data-title="Quantity">
         <span class="sr-only">{{ $item ['quantity'] }} </span>
         <!-- Quantity -->
         <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
         <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
             <div class="col">
             <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" type="text" value="1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-auto pr-1">
             <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                 <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
             </a>
             <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                 <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
             </a>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- End Quantity -->
     </td>
     
     <td data-title="Total">
     <span class=""></span> 
  </td>
  </tr>
                               
@endforeach
```

**web.php**

```
    Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart');
    Route::get('/cart/{id}', 'CartController@show')->name('cart');
    Route::get('/cart/{products}', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add')->middleware('auth');
```

**products.blade.php**

```
@foreach($products as $p) 
   <li class="col-6 col-md-3 col-wd-2gdot4 product-item">
       <div class="product-item__outer h-100">
           <div class="product-item__inner px-xl-4 p-3">
           <div class="product-item__body pb-xl-2" >
           <div class="mb-2" class="font-size-12 text-gray-5">{{ $p ['prod_sub_category'] }}</div>
           <h5 class="mb-1 product-item__title" class="text-blue font-weight-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}
           </h5>
           <div class="mb-2">
               <a href="{{route('single',$p->id)}}" class="d-block text-center">
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$p ['prod_image_path']) }}" alt="Image Description">
               </a>
           </div>
           <div class="flex-center-between mb-1">
           <div class="prodcut-price">
           <div class="text-gray-100">LKR {{ $p ['prod_price'] }}.00</div>
           </div>
           <div class="d-none d-xl-block prodcut-add-cart">
               <a href="{{route('cart.add',$p->id)}}" class="btn-add-cart btn-primary transition-3d-hover"><i class="ec ec-add-to-cart"></i></a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
       <div class="product-item__footer">
       <div class="border-top pt-2 flex-center-between flex-wrap">
           <a href="../shop/compare.html" class="text-gray-6 font-size-13"><i class="ec ec-compare mr-1 font-size-15"></i> Compare</a>
           <a href="../shop/wishlist.html" class="text-gray-6 font-size-13"><i class="ec ec-favorites mr-1 font-size-15"></i> Wishlist</a>
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how is it not working, what do you want from that which is not happening, specify more

Comment: I need to display as cart.blade.php  But the cart page is displaying as empty?

Comment: @bhucho can you able to find out?

Comment: first check first cartItems is received in blade, if yes, try $item->name instead of $item ['name'], $item->quantity instead of $item ['quantity'] etc